# How to pass more than one parameters using display tag with escapeXml="true"?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, displaytag

I am using display tag 1.2.1 version and I want to pass more than one parameter. How to pass more than one parameters using display tag with escapeXml property true.

Comment: Where to pass? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Alex I need a href link on my record in table and when i click on the link it need to go to action page(another page) the url should be like follow, http://action_page.html?parm1=123&param2=456 I tried using `code` <c:url value="..." var="theUrl" /> But it is not working for me because I need to keep escapeXml property true.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what exactly does not work. Can you post what you do (`<display:column>`...) and what you expect and your error?

Comment: @Alex I tried both of following ways,
 
(`<display:column escapeXml="true" title="Detail View">    
    <a href="action_page.html?param1=123&param2=456">View</a>
</display:column>`)

(`<display:column escapeXml="true" title="Detail View">
    <c:url value="action_page.html" var="myUrl">
        <c:param name="param1" value="123"/>
        <c:param name="param1" value="456"/>
    </c:url>
    <a href="<c:out value="${myUrl"}/>">View</a>
</display:column>`)

I have to keep escapeXml="true" because I need to export the result data from table. Then it shows the plain html code instead of link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is to show `link` in `html` and that should not appear in the exported data.
If it is you can define a `display:column` with `media` type html.

```
<display:column media="html"  titleKey="DetailView">
    <a href="action_page.html?param1=123&param2=456">View</a>                       
</display:column>
<display:column media="xml"  titleKey="DetailView">View</display:column>
```